# How to use select2 with Meteor?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, meteor, jquery-select2

can someone explain to me how select2 works with Meteor? I am using [zimme:select2-boostrap3-css](https://atmospherejs.com/zimme/select2-bootstrap3-css) and I have no clue on how to use it.

I checked both the original [select2 github page](http://select2.github.io/select2/) and the one from the [package](https://github.com/t0m/select2-bootstrap-css/tree/bootstrap3). The first one explains how to use it without Meteor.

Do I just add the jQuery code to one of my *.js-files in order to get it to work?

In HTML:

```
<select class="input" id="clientName" name="clientName">
    {{#each getClients}}
        <option value="{{clientName}}" data-id={{_id}}>{{clientName}}</option>
    {{/each}}
</select>
```

In JS:

```
$("#clientName").select2();
```

Because this doesn't work.

When loading my page I get this error `Uncaught TypeError: $(...).select2 is not a function`.

Comment: It looks like the meteor version is only copying the CSS - maybe add the javascript somewhere, like client/select2.js

Comment: Agreed, this package is css only. You need one of the actual [select2](https://atmospherejs.com/zimme/select2-bootstrap3-css?q=select2) packages to get the js.

Comment: You need to include the Select2 JavaScript code.

Comment: Would my approach be okay if I had everything in place?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Uncaught TypeError: $(...).select2 is not a function

The error above happening because you haven't included the JavaScript for Select2, as identified in the comments.  The atmosphere [package you linked to](https://atmospherejs.com/zimme/select2-bootstrap3-css) is just for providing Bootstrap-esque styling *on top of* the existing Select2 package.

You should also include [`meteor add natestrauser:select2`](https://atmospherejs.com/natestrauser/select2)

The next problem you may run into is that when the JavaScript runs, `<select class="input" >` might not be loaded into the DOM so `$("#clientName")` won't find anything.  To wait to initialize Select2 until the page is loaded, you should wrap the code in the jQuery's DOM ready function `$(function(){});` and wrap that in the `Meteor.Startup()` for good measure like this:

```js
Meteor.startup(function () {
  $(function(){
    $("#clientName").select2();
  });
});
```

#### [Working Demo in Meteorpad](http://meteorpad.com/pad/pHc7QwybBz6wXBRsg/Select2)

**Further Reading**:

- [How to run JQuery code when document is ready in Meteor?](https://forums.meteor.com/t/3121)

Comment: Thank you very much. It still didn't work immediately but your Further Reading link gave me the information I needed! I had to use Template.onRendered to do the jQuery magic. Today I learned something new.