# Select2 not getting loaded in template. [Meteor + Blaze]

Tags: javascript, meteor, ecmascript-6, jquery-select2, meteor-blaze

Before marking question duplicate, I want to make clear that I have already tried all the ways possible (e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33422127/how-to-use-select2-with-meteor?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)) to simply load a select2 dropdown on a simple page in Meteor.

Below is simple code to understand my select2 application procedure.

**ManageRoles.js**

```
Template.ManageRoles.onRendered(function() {
    $(".roleSelect").select2();
});
```

**ManageRoles.html**

```
<form class="assignRoleForm">                              
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <label>Roles</label>
            <select class="roleSelect form-control" multiple="multiple" required>
                <option value="">Select Option</option>
                <option value="1">ADMIN</option>
                <option value="2">MANAGER</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
    <br/>
    <div class="text-center">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">  Assign  </button>
        <button type="button"  class="btn btn-danger"> Close </button>
    </div>
</form>
```

**select2 Import structure**

```
root\client\vendor\select2\select2-bootstrap.css
root\client\vendor\select2\select2.js
root\client\vendor\select2\style\select2.css
```

**Below is the snapshot of the current output.**

[image]

****************** **Updated** *******************

Upon doing this `console.log($('.roleSelect').get(0));` I get below in console log

```
<select class="roleSelect form-control" multiple="multiple" required="">
    <option value="">Select Option</option>
    <option value="fov9sPjiXtbRdJccR">ADMIN</option>
    <option value="ga4p3FwQ76LH4Nq8y">MANAGER</option>
</select>
```

Comment: What about `$("#roleSelect").get(0).select2()`? And does logging `$("#roleSelect").get(0)` to console even prints some element?

Comment: @Jankapunkt: Question updated with your asked console output.

Comment: in your original code, `roleSelect` is an `id`, but in your update it's a `class` - did you switch halfway through?

Comment: Yes! I am trying ways possible to make it work still I haven't found the reason.

Answer (score 0):

I would try the following:

```
Template.ManageRoles.onRendered(function() {
    this.$(".roleSelect").select2({
    placeholder: 'Select Option'
  });
});
```

And then in the HTML leave the first option blank:

```
<option value=""></option>
```

Comment: Did using `this.$` syntax help you?